# Dynamic paginator / computed property not updating

Tags: vue.js

I have a dynamic paginator that isn't updating based on the underlying computed property (which IS updating, I have verified from the console).

```
    <template v-for="(p, i) in pageStart + 4">
        <li v-if="p <= lastPage && i <= 4" @click="getPage(p)" :class="{active: isActive(p)}"><a href="#">{{ p }}</a></li>
    </template>
```

In the above example, pageStart is a computed property that changes correctly as I click on the various paginator numbers - but the numbers themselves don't change. In other words 'p' in this v-for loop is never updated, so I'm always stuck with a paginator numbered 1-5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your for loop logic. The `v-for` is going to loop from `1` to `pageStart + 4` for every value of `pageStart`. At the same time, you have `i <= 4` so it only renders the first 4 every time `pageStart` changes.

You probably want something more like:

```
<template v-for="p in 4">
    <li v-if="p + pageStart <= lastPage" 
        @click="getPage(p + pageStart)" 
        :class="{active: isActive(p + pageStart)}">
        <a href="#">{{ p + pageStart }}</a>
    </li>
</template>
```

Comment: You are an absolute legend.